# Uboot bootloader linux image booting issue

Tags: elf, bootloader, u-boot

I am currently working on bootloaders to boot linux through SD/MMC Card. I have written a SPI Driver through which the SD/MMC Card is interfaced to get the DTB and the kernel image(uImage).

I have tried to boot in 2 methods and only one work. The 2 methods are :

```
1. The vmlinux(ELF) which is generated as a intermediate step in BBL generation is 
   taken and the converted to uImage using the mkimage command with headers.
2. The vmlinux(ELF) which is generated as a intermediate step in BBL generation is
   taken and then converted to BIN using objcopy command, after which mkimage 
   is used to generate the uImage with the same header details(as in 1).
```

In the 2 cases the second situation is the one that is booting while the first method shows ***illegal instruction*** error. I have also tried to start the kernel with the vmlinux directly too and even in that process the same ***illegal instruction*** error is arising. From my observation when we start any program in ELF format this ***illegal instruction*** error is throwing while the BIN is working fine.

Is there any place to check if the ELF loader or any other related thing has to be included?

Comment: I understand that the uImage method is deprecated but since the BIN based uImage is starting and ELF based uImage shows error I think this has to be resolved for any ELF based image to start in u-boot

Comment: Are you certain that the vmlinux is in fact a valid ELF application and can even be started via, I assume, `bootelf` ?

Comment: I assume they are correct as the BIN version of the same file when used for creating the uImage seems to work. Also. that same vmlinux is being used to create the bbl (which starts when started through GDB)

Comment: Well, no.  The binary version of the file strips out things like the ELF header.  Working via GDB is also not the same.

Comment: I have stripped the ELF header from the vmlinux(ELF) to generate the BIN file, which is working right now. I have the same vmlinux(ELF) which is used as payload to riscv-pk to generate bbl is working when booted through GDB. From this I mean to say that they seem to be a valid application.